# Access sql convert number to - or . for confidentiality

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to convert certain data in an access database from a number to a dash. Essentially certain data that is provisional I dont want to show in final database.

Im guessing this should be easy but hitting a brick wall / having an idiot moment. Trying this but it is not working as there is a clash between updating a number to text.

```
UPDATE Table SET Table.Data=“-”
WHERE Table.Year=2018 AND Table.Code="B"
```

Assume I am missing something easy. Grateful for any advice.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? Is the data a numeric field? (a numeric field can't contain a dash for obvious reasons, a dash is not a number).

Comment: Yeah the data is a numeric field. Is there a work around for this? Essentially convert parts of numeric field to text?

Comment: If it's a numeric field you cant store a dash in it. Also the font in your code snippet is a mess so if your actual code has those goofy double quotes they won't work.

Comment: @jyh5 If you want to change digits to dashes I suppose you know that yiou will not be able to use this field as a number. So change its data type to text.

Comment: Why would you store nonsense in your database?  If the data is private, use a password field.  See this: https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/assign-password-data-type-to-a-specific-field-in-access-2010/

Answer (score 0):

A numeric field cannot be `'-'`, because that is a string.  You could use a value such as `-1`:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Table.Data = -1
    WHERE Table.Year = 2018 AND Table.Code = "B";
```

Or you could just use `NULL`:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Table.Data = NULL
    WHERE Table.Year = 2018 AND Table.Code = "B";
```